# Get key for coinbase account in go-ethereum SimulatedBackend

Tags: go-ethereum, coinbase

What's the best way to 1) pre-fund 2) get a signing key for the coinbase account in the `go-ethereum` Simulated Back-end?

Right now the simulated back-end coinbase account seems to default to 0x0 but I'm not able to control that with GenesisAlloc.

For more info, [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/7f3362595a3bdf1c27b17f16b7d90d89882312ab/accounts/abi/bind/backends/simulated.go) is the code section for SimulatedBackend. I can get the Coinbase account with `Blockchain().CurrentBlock().Coinbase()`, but would like to pre-allocate some funds/get the signing key at the time of calling `NewSimulatedBackend`.